# Not able to access storage even if storage permission is granted in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using the permission_handler package to request permissions on Android. A user is able to download a file to the downloads folder when he clicks on "Allow" in the Permission.storage popup. (We are calling it Permission.storage when the user installs the app.)

The issue is that if a user clicks on "Don't allow" the first time and "Allow" the second time in other flows in the app, we are still getting a permission denied error and the user is not able to download files like above flow. I've logged and checked the value of the status; it is coming as PermissionStatus.granted only which is expected. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Below is the error log

I/flutter ( 8170): could not download file FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/codes.txt' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)

```
/// Permission snippet of first time
 final permission =
        GetPlatform.isAndroid ? Permission.storage : Permission.photos;
    final status = await permission.status;
    if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      await permission.request().isGranted;
    }

/// Snippet when user clicks on download second time 
  final permission = Permission.storage;
        final status = await permission.status;
        debugPrint('>>>Status $status'); /// here it is coming as PermissionStatus.granted
        if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
          await permission.request().isGranted;
          debugPrint('>>> ${await permission.status}');
        }
        directory = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
       ///perform other stuff to download file
```

Comment: when the user clicks on the download button again, check whether the user has given the permission or not, if not then you call the permission function again.

Comment: Yes @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ am checking for the same. Now second time even if user clicks on Allow , we are not able to download file.

Comment: you have to use state management for this.

Comment: @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ what is the issue with my code ? why i need to use state management?I've updated my code can you check again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when permission_handler package send request to user with `request()` function, we made in `await` so after close dialog you check second time if permission granted or not and if permission granted then perform other stuff to download file else you can again send request for the permission.

```
/// Snippet when user clicks on download second time 
final permission = Permission.storage;
final status = await permission.status;
debugPrint('>>>Status $status'); /// here it is coming as PermissionStatus.granted
if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
  await permission.request();
  if(await permission.status.isGranted){
    directory = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
    ///perform other stuff to download file
  } else {
   await permission.request();
  }
  debugPrint('>>> ${await permission.status}');
}
directory = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
///perform other stuff to download file
```

Answer (score 0):

uses add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
```

add this code

```
<application
    android:label="testavatarbetter"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYOc0.png)